# Memory allocation with std430 qualifier

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm using the compute shader bound with a SSAO. And I use the following structure in the compute shader:

```
struct Particle                 
{                       
    vec4 pAnds;                     
    vec3 velocity;                  
    float lifespan;             
    float age;                  
};

layout (std430, binding = 0) buffer members_in
{
    Particle particle[];
} input_data;
```

yet it seems that the memory block allocated for each of these data structure is not equal to (4 + 3 + 1 + 1) * 4. And I also tried another one:

```
struct Particle                 
{                       
    vec4 pAnds;                     
    vec3 velocity;                  
    float lifespan;             
};
```

This time it worked fine. I was wondering how the memory is allocated with std430 qualifier. How to make my first data structure work just as the second one?

updated:
I changed it to the following form:

```
struct Particle
{                           
    float px, py, pz, s;
    float vx, vy, vz;
    float lifespan;
    float age;
};
```

This time it worked fine, but I still have no idea why there's problem using vec4 / vec3.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think each particle needs to be aligned to a 16 byte boundary (assuming you're running on x86) if you've got an array of particles there.  Your second example does this (4 * 4 + 3 * 4 + 1 * 4) = 32.  Your first example doesn't (4 * 4 + 3 * 4 + 1 * 4 + 1 * 4) = 36.  So I think you may need to add 1 float of padding.

Comment: ... or even 3 floats of padding actually.

Comment: @Robinson I used four float instead of vec4, and three float instead of vec3, and it turned out to be correct.

Comment: Yes, the alignment will be 1 rather than 4 (vec4) if you use floats.  Though I'm not sure if that affects performance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the std430 Layout Rules:

> Structure alignment is the same as the alignment for the biggest structure member, where three-component vectors are not rounded up to the size of four-component vectors. Each structure will start on this alignment, and its size will be the space needed by its members, according to the previous rules, rounded up to a multiple of the structure alignment.

The alignments for vec4 is four times the size of float.

Source: OpenGL Programming Guide, 8th Edition

---

First example:

```
struct Particle {
    vec4 pAnds;      // 4 * 4 bytes
    vec3 velocity;   // 3 * 4 bytes
    float lifespan;  // 1 * 4 bytes
    float age;       // 1 * 4 bytes
};
```

The biggest member of the structure is `vec4 pAnds` and it has 16 byte alignment. Therefore the structure's alignment is also 16 bytes, meaning, that inside an array each structure has to start at a position multiple of 16. In order to satisfy that, a 12 byte padding will be appended to the end of each structure.

---

Second example:

```
struct Particle {
    vec4 pAnds;      // 4 * 4 bytes
    vec3 velocity;   // 3 * 4 bytes
    float lifespan;  // 1 * 4 bytes
};
```

The structure has an alignment of 16 bytes and the size of the structure nicely fits into 2 times the alignment of the structure.

---

Third example:

```
struct Particle {
    float px, py, pz, s;
    float vx, vy, vz;
    float lifespan;
    float age;
};
```

The structure doesn't have any elements bigger than one size of float, therefore the alignment of the structure is only 4 bytes.

---

The workaround could be inserting an array of floats as an explicit padding or trying to pack your data tightly into a size multiple of the structure's alignment.